# What is the philosophical term used to describe the "fullness of the universe"?

Tags: terminology

If I remember it correctly, there is a specific term used to describe the fullness/packedness of the universe by ancient Greek philosophers. i.e. There is no "void" in the universe.

Can somebody help me with the term? I feel like Flaubert when he could not recall the exact term he wanted to use.

Comment: [Plenitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_plenitude) ? But the principle of plenitude does not assert that "there is no void"...

Comment: Both of your answers mentioned something I was ignorant of and I am grateful. However, I vaguely remember the term has something to do with metaphysics on particles, such as what Democritus said about atoms and may influenced Descartes' Vortex Theory, but please don't be misled by my memory if your intuition tells you otherwise.

Comment: The word "plentitude" may actually work better in the context of the phenomena I intend to describe. Thank you.
However, I do wish people who know the answer shed light on the topic or correct my shoddy memory on the subject.

Comment: See also [Plenism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horror_vacui_(physics)).

Comment: Alas, yes! Yes! That's it! Eureka! Thank you! You know so much!

Comment: I did not know "Horror vacuum" has a metaphysics definition and only glanced over its definition in arts. I do apologize. I love the definition in art as well, so I will post the old link here, as it may be useful to some.

And if you are willing, please submit "plenism" as the answer.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horror_vacui

Comment: "πλήρης" = full

Comment: The 'shāntipātha' - peace chant - at the start of the Brihadaranyaka and Ishavasya Upanishads has a similar idea. It goes "Om, That is full, this is full. This Fullness has been projected from that Fullness. When this Fullness merges in that Fullness, all that remains is Fullness. Om. Peace, peace, peace." 'That fullness' refers to the Unmanifested. 'This fullness' refers to the Manifested.

Comment: Imma throw the word "pleroma" in here, as this also refers to fullness, if usually in a Christian setting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term is [Plenism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horror_vacui_(physics)).

See [Descartes' Physics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes-physics/#3) and compare with [Aristotle's Natural Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-natphil/#2); and see also [The void: Antiquity](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/newton-stm/#2.1).

Plenism identify the view that the *physical* universe contains no vacuums.

See [Plenitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_plenitude) for the *metaphysical* thesis asserting that the universe contains all possible forms of existence.

Answer (score 2):

PLENUM ITSELF IS A GOOD WORD. In Sanskrit we speak of emptiness as sunyatva and of fullness as purnatva . The Scholarly volume of essays edited by  Bettina Bauer and John R. Dupuche may be of some interest to you. It may not lead to your recollection of ‘Flaubert’ per se, but it will awake many other ‘memories’...some perhaps even from a last-life-time! Namaste!